# CSS Background When Using Fixed Header Row

Tags: css

I don't know too much about css, but I found a way to freeze the top header of my table. The problem is, when I apply a background color to the column it doesn't fill in the entire cell. I'd like the background to fill in all of the way to the bottom of the cell. Am I going to be able to do this, given the way I'm freezing the header row of the table?

Example

[Background not filling to bottom of cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Vez.png)

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 98%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr > th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <table class="table table-fixed ">
        <thead class="active">
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: #f0ee6f;">N/A</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">N/A</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">N/A</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">History</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: #f0ee6f;">N/A</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">N/A</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">N/A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Comments</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: #f0ee6f;">N/A</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">N/A</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">N/A</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your screenshot looks pretty different from the result of the code you provided. Could you explain what you're trying to do, and what led to the problem seen in the picture?